# Embed Google Maps area to put it in an App (build with xamarin) and lay picture over the map

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, bing-maps, google-maps-api-2, xamarin.mobile

Right now I am working on a project for university. I'm really struggling due to my not existent experience with xamarin. The plan is to make an app for a zoo and there has to be a function that can tell you where exactly you are with GPS and to show that on a picture of the zoo map. There are many many problems because the map has to be turned about 75 degrees. So how can I combine it with gmaps oder Bing maps or something in order to work properly. Thanks in advance

Florian Zumpf 
Mother's tongue : German

Comment: Probably you don't need google maps, if you display your own map anyway. Using google maps just for the marker looks like overkill... I'd create a georeferenced version of the zoo map (i.e. know lat/long of the four corners) and then display the marker on the map manually. _If_ you insist on google maps, have a look at https://github.com/TorbenK/TK.CustomMap for xamarin forms.

Comment: Thanks. That seems like a way better idea that the one I had at first.  Thank you